# Uwsgi emperor vassal startup order?

Tags: uwsgi

I want to use the uwsgi emperor to run multiple services. However, there is some interdependency between services, such that e.g. service A requires service B to be up and running when it is brought up. Is there anyway to encode a startup ordering in the uwsgi emperor? I tried naming the vassal files in such a way that they order lexicographically in the same startup order that I wanted, but this doesn't appear to have the desired affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the --wait-for-socket option could be the best approach. The instance using it will not start until the socket of the other one is ready to accept requests.